# Templating system or PHP include statement?

Tags: php, html, templates

Simple question really; why would I want to use templating system like Smarty to separate HTML and PHP code, when I can simply use a PHP include statement in HTML files?

Is my logic wrong?

---

EDIT: Thank you for your answers, I am somewhat a beginner so let me get this right. As far as I understand, regarding to my question, it is perfectly OK to use php own statements to successfully implement templating system. Statements like include and on read.

I don't get it though why would it be more messy to use php than using some other system which is nothing but a nuisance to understand while php has its own nice simple system implemented just for such use...

Comment: Because of the syntax sugar. PHP templating is messy.

Comment: use what ever you like, however you like, when ever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a matter of good practices rather than logic itself.

There's several things you as a developer should keep in mind when creating a website, namely security, efficiency, ease to maintain, not necessarily by that order.

I have found out that making an MVC architecture will allow you to keep everything neatly seperated. You need to do it right, which may take a few attempts, but that's a part of being a programmer.

While playing around with MVC, I found out that using a Registry was particularly effective. While the application runs the model logic, you can add data to the registry. When it ends, you start creating the output html.

Now, this varies from person to person, but here's what I found to be the best approach for my case:

Output the page frame / barebones / whatever you call it. Even if it's just the html head tag. Use requires to load templates into the empty sections of the page. On the template code, you can simply read from the registry to figure out what data to print. You can have smaller templates inside other templates, with little no no added complexity, especially if you look at it as function calls inside other functions, except this is view logic, not model.

This gives both the programmers and designers full flexibility, even if one of the groups changes their code drastically, as long as the data in the registry keeps the same name tags.

Honestly, I never used a templating system, because from what I had seen, the mathod I described above created more readable code and it fulfilled all my needs. Just because other toys exist, you don't have to play with them. In fact, if you don't really need to use any external stuff, you shouldn't, which will keep your code smaller, faster, and easier to understand, since there's less code that you didn't write in it, which will affect efficiency and maintainability.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer, I am somewhat a beginner so let me get this right. As far as I understand, regarding to my question, it is perfectly OK to use php own statements to successfully implement templating system. Statements like include and on read. I don't get it though why would it be more messy than using some other system which is nothing but a nuisance to understand while php has its own nice simple system

Comment: Because most if not all templating systems add their own syntax. When you're the one man army building the whole site by yourself, that's another set of syntax rules you need to keep in mind while coding, although those kinds of systems will allow you to do more complex stuff with less code.

When you're coding, you need to keep a lot of concepts in mind, including the syntax of any language you're using. The more you need  to keep in mind, the harder it is to get stuff done. Also, when you're interrupted, you take longer to pick the concepts up and be productive again.

Comment: So overall if I am doing everything by myself you recommend using only php but if a team is building an online solution it is better to use a system because it is simpler?

Comment: Like I said, this varies with the programmer. I can only back this up with personal experience, and that experience is that the less things you have to keep in mind at all times when developing the faster you get things done. You don't need those systems because you have a team. You need them if they increase productivity, which I don't believe they do when coding solo. When you have a team, as long as you have a registry for the data you'll output, you should be fine, but that's more about MVC than templating.

Comment: Thank you, based on discussion on this page I am even more confident I can do just as good with only php and I don't need fancy templating systems. I just don't have the nerves to start learning about Smarty or similar at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

It is to provide a simplified subset of PHP's functionality to template authors who are generally front end developers who don't have the skills to play in the back end.

Also it promotes better MVC design in that the subset of functionality offered by most template language includes only functions that deal with the view concerns of an application, making it either difficult or impossible to do model manipulation in the view.